# CORS from Firebase Hosting to REST api to other sub-domain

Tags: rest, firebase, cors, firebase-hosting

I have hosted my web-app on "Firebase Hosting" on my own custom domain for eg:- **webapp.example.com**. I have enabled CORS so that browser wont block it.

My REST services are hosted on another sub-domain eg:- **api.example.com**

Now when I am calling API from my web-app it says "Failed to load response" and fails.

Status code is 200 though.

**Response Headers:**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,PUT,OPTIONS,DELETE,PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 28 Apr 2019 09:37:30 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

**Request Headers**

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,x-referral
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: https://webapp.example.com
Referer: https://webapp.example.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

Any idea why this is happening or how should I fix it.